# Random forest cross validated k fold with caret package R best auc

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation, r-caret, k-fold

I have a fairly serious problem that I haven't been able to solve for many days!
I cannot understand exactly how the traincontrol function of the caret package works in R.
I need to cross validate (10-fold) a random forest and thought that the caret package could automatically pick only 1 test set (10% of my dataset) at a time (10 times, 10 different test set) and validate the random forest on it, training on the 90% of dataset.
All the tutorials on the web enter the Trainset for the train function, and the testset for the predict function... but why?!

Specifically, I need to classify a binary category ~ respect to 5 mix variables (stepwise, starting from a pair of variables) and study specificity, sensitivity, accuracy and AUC. Then i need to choose best variables for model (Best AUC) and adding another variable at model, repeating the iter.

Can someone kindly explain to me how it works once and for all?
And if there are examples of both manual loop of cross-validation repeated or automatic with caret!

I would prefer to learn a manual loop, so that I can use it for various analyzes.
I would be very grateful to you.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: if i get it correct, your question is about how cross-validation with caret works? It's better to focus it onto 1 problem. we cannot write your pipeline or perform all the task within the space of 1 question

Comment: My principal problem is understand if caret package can do automatically the kfold cross validation, inserting into train function directly the dataset and not the trainset.

Example:

trcontrol = trainControl(method='cv', 
                        number=10, savePredictions = T)

model = train(y ~ . , data=data, method = "rf", trControl = trcontrol)

And not:

modelNOT = train(y ~ . , data = trainset, method = "rf", trControl = trcontrol)

Answer (score 0):

We can break this down in parts:

> the caret package could automatically pick only 1 test set (10% of my
> dataset) at a time (10 times, 10 different test set) and validate the
> random forest on it, training on the 90% of dataset.

Yes, this will be done on the training set you have provided. For example, like in most tutorials you have seen, we can set the trainControl to return all the results using `returnResamp="all"` and this will be clear:

```
set.seed(111)
dat = iris
dat$Species = factor(ifelse(dat$Species == "versicolor","v","o"))
ix = sample(nrow(dat),100)
trainset = dat[ix,]
testset = dat[-ix,]

trcontrol = trainControl(method='cv', number=10, savePredictions = T,
classProbs = TRUE,summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,returnResamp="all")

model = train(Species ~ . , data=trainset, method = "rf", trControl = trcontrol,metric="ROC") 

model$resample
    
              ROC      Sens Spec mtry Resample
1  1.0000000 0.8333333 1.00    2   Fold01
2  1.0000000 0.8333333 1.00    3   Fold01
3  1.0000000 0.8333333 1.00    4   Fold01
4  1.0000000 1.0000000 0.75    2   Fold02
5  1.0000000 1.0000000 0.75    3   Fold02
6  1.0000000 1.0000000 0.75    4   Fold02
```

You can see now, for every test fold, the ROC (also the AUC under ROC curve) is being calculated. In total, for each parameter of mtry, it is evaluated on 10 folds (with the others used as training). And then you take the average and select model with the best AUC:

```
Random Forest 

100 samples
  4 predictor
  2 classes: 'o', 'v' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 90, 90, 89, 90, 90, 90, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  ROC        Sens       Spec
  2     1.0000000  0.9523810  0.95
  3     1.0000000  0.9523810  0.95
  4     0.9958333  0.9357143  0.95

ROC was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
```

Now the test fold (within the training) might be small, and ideally once we have a rough idea of the hyper parameter to use, we want to check the predictability of our model on a larger unseen set.

Hence we retain another of the data to check this. And this is normally call test or validation, like what is done at the start of this example, we can check this:

```
confusionMatrix(predict(model,testset),testset$Species)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  o  v
         o 37  0
         v  2 11
```

So in this case, we see it can predict unseen data pretty well. It really depends on your data and how likely your model would overfit.

Comment: It seems so difficult to explain my problem.
My problem is to understand why I first have to split my dataset into trainset and testset if the train control function should do it automatically 10 times, scrolling 9 train sets each time and testing on 1?
At that point, what sense would it make to use caret and not directly a random forest on 90% of the dataset and predict on the remaining 10%?

Imagining that I have an n = 500, on the final confusion matrix I should get 500 observations and predictions, but here I only get 50, which is the test set.

I'm so sad :(

Comment: you do a 10 fold so that you can see the distribution of your errors. Yes you can do it once, but let's say if you are lucky with that 1 sampling, you might get a very optimistic AUC or accuracy.

Comment: I want to do it 10 times, not once!!! but why i have to insert trainset in model function and not all dataset! 
Maybe I can't explain well.
Does Traincontrol do the kfold automatically? so why i have to insert the trainset (made up of 90%) rather than the entire dataset? Shouldn't he automatically block 9 and test on 1, 10 times?

Comment: in my answer, you can see that ```train()``` does the kfold automatically. please read the code carefully... You can use the entire dataset in train(), just that you don't have an extra validation dataset, to see how your model performs on a larger dataset. Again please read my answer again... I have touched specifically on this

Comment: Thank u for your pacience :)

I still don't understand what need I have to divide my dataset, if I want the forecast of the whole dataset and not just 10% of it.
If i use your code i have a confusion matrix of 50 observations and not of 500, like my dataset. I wanna train on 9 and test on 1, i wanna save results and go to other 9 train and test on 1, save and repeat the process...

Answer (score -1):

Here are some thoughts:

### **Feature Engineering**

Instead of applying the model over each df feature,
I suggest to apply a feature selection based on your data;

This table could be an option to select the features,
If you wish to compare the response variable (binary category) against other categorical variables use the chi-squared test if instead these variables are continuous you could use
ANOVA test instead

```
###############################################################
#                Categorical           Continuous             #
#  Categorical   Chi-Squared Test         ANOVA               # 
#  Continuous    Chi-Squared Test         Pearson Correlation #
###############################################################
```

Of course you could use other non-parametric statistical test as Kruskal-Wallis,
However I would need to see your df structure in order to give you a final test opinion.

### **Train Set vs. Validation Set**

A: Train set is used to get the model to learn and by that to estimate his parameters, while Test set is used only to assess model performance; that's why train function and test  function should be the same.

For more info you can dive into here:https://towardsdatascience.com/train-validation-and-test-sets-72cb40cba9e7

### Model Building:

For the model building, you could use `h2o.ai` package
Here's the documentation: https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.randomForest.html

This function has some parameters that you could use to set your model:
As well it already handles specificity, the task to report sensitivity, accuracy, recall, F1-score and AUC.

```
stopping_metric = c("AUTO", "deviance", "logloss", "MSE", "RMSE", "MAE", "RMSLE",
    "AUC", "AUCPR", "lift_top_group", "misclassification", "mean_per_class_error",
    "custom", "custom_increasing")

# This parameter let you choose "AUC" as the model metric to get optimized.
```

```
 nfolds = 0 
 fold_assignment = c("AUTO", "Random", "Modulo", "Stratified")

# This parameter let you choose the number of folds as the resampling method to be perform 
# in order to validate your model, with no need of iteration.
```

```
keep_cross_validation_models= TRUE
keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE
keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment = TRUE

# This parameter let you see individual accuracy by fold.
```

Comment: how does this answer OPs question on cross-validation and what happens with trainset and test set?

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: Imagine you just get 50 observations on your test set, you could try to oversample your data, this will help to balance classes without giving up randomness, as well this will give your model an AUC closer to 1 and you will tackle the low data volume problem; doing 10x times CV will just duplicate the model validation work, this would make your ml pipeline slower. Please read h2o.ai documentation, it already handles this work for you.